# Multiple SSH Clients on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh, path

I have multiple SSH clients on my mac, one is at

```
/usr/local/bin//ssh
```

and the other one is at

```
/usr/bin/ssh
```

I want to use `/usr/bin/ssh` always! My `PATH` looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I am wondering how to set default `SSH` to `/usr/bin/ssh` without modify the `PATH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an alias (and this is one of the rare exceptions where an alias—instead of a function—is OK).

```
alias ssh=/usr/bin/ssh
```

I am assuming that simply uninstalling `/usr/local/bin/ssh` is not an option.